# How to add class attribute to options for select tag in rails 4?

Tags: css, class, ruby-on-rails-4, select, drop-down-menu

i am writing the options for select like this. it is not giving any error but class attribute is not coming in the generated html.

```
<%= f.select(:late_penalty, options_for_select([["Days in Week", "Days in Week"],
                                            ["Days in Month", "Days in Month"]], :selected => @late_early.late_penalty) , { :class => 'my_style_class' })%>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
 <%= f.select(:late_penalty,
 options_for_select([
                    ["Days in Week", "Days in Week"],
                    ["Days in Month", "Days in Month"]],
                    :selected => @late_early.late_penalty),
                    { } , { :class => 'my_style_class' })%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that HTML attributes must be passed as the fourth argument to `select`, but you're supplying them as the third argument. (The third argument is for options like `:include_blank`.) Here's what you want:

```
<%= f.select(:late_penalty, 
      options_for_select(
        [ [ "Days in Week", "Days in Week" ],
          [ "Days in Month", "Days in Month" ]
        ],
        :selected => @late_early.late_penalty
      ),
      nil,
      { :class => 'my_style_class' }
    )
%>
```